# Fix positions of elements when expanded

Tags: html, css

There are two boxes (**Box1**, **Box2**) which expand when I hover on using Margins and Paddings. They are given custom classes and designs. They both Float left so that they can be next to each other.

The HTML:

```
<div class="contentbox-lg stk-left bg-red">
  <p class="contentbox-content">Box1</p>
</div>
<div class="contentbox-lg stk-left bg-blue">
  <p class="contentbox-content">Box2</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Content Box Main CSS */

.contentbox-lg {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.contentbox-lg:hover {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 73px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.contentbox-content {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.stk-left {
  float: left;
}


/* Content Box Colors */

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.bg-blue:hover {
  background-color: #3498db
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

.bg-red:hover {
  background-color: #e74c3c
}
```

The problem which makes me suffer from is when **Box1** is hovered on, the second box slightly moves towards the right and when **Box2** is hovered, the first box doesn't move. I don't want **Box2** to move when **Box1** is being hovered on.

Find jsfiddle Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shahrozasif1/7cjm23uj/1/)

Comment: Can't access your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is the best way to inline boxes, but with your code you can do this:

1) Change your padding to even number (padding: 74px instead padding 73px)
2) Then, you just add margin-right: -27px; inside .contentbox-lg:hover

That is:

```
.contentbox-lg:hover {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 74px; /* change to 74px */
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: -27px; /* add this line */
}
```

Comment: No need to change `Padding` to `74px`, you can change `Margin-Right` to `-25px` as well but both can be correct.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get rid of the movement on hover is to use `position:absolute` on the boxes

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pdka1bgh/3/)

```
.contentbox-lg {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.contentbox-lg { left: 200px;}
.contentbox-lg:first-child { left: 0;}
```

Comment: This answer can be right but `Position:absolute` isn't always worthy. Example: If I want to add on more text for my Paragraph, the `ContentBoxes` would be a distraction. So I most likely prefer the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative `margin-right:-25px` on the `:hover`

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/lajaka/edit?html,css,output)

```
.contentbox-lg:hover {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 73px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right:-25px;
}
```